# How to add xml file data into ArangoDb?

Tags: java, json, xml, arangodb

```
<InputParameters>
    <Textbox>
        <Text>ABCD</Text>
        <Text>EFGH</Text>
        <Text>HIJK</Text>
    </Textbox>
</InputParameters>
```

Suppose i have to add this xml file data into arangodb. How would one able to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 2.7.1 the aragodb-java-driver supports writing (createDocumentRaw(...)) and reading (getDocumentRaw(...)) of
raw strings.

Example:

```
arangoDriver.createDocumentRaw("testCollection", "{\"test\":123}", 
    true, false);
```

With [JsonML](http://www.jsonml.org/) you can convert a XML string into a JSON string and store it into ArangoDB:

```
// writing
String xml = "<recipe name=\"bread\" prep_time=\"5 mins\"</recipe> ";
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONML.toJSONObject(string);
DocumentEntity<String> entity =     arangoDriver.createDocumentRaw(
         "testCollection", jsonObject.toString(), true, false);
String documentHandle = entity.getDocumentHandle();

// reading
String json = arangoDriver.getDocumentRaw(documentHandle, null, null);
JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(str);
String xml2 = JSONML.toString(jsonObject2));
```

You can find more examples in the arangodb-java-driver git [repository](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/example/document/RawDocumentExample.java).

Comment: We added an in detail description for this in our [ArangoDB Cookbook](https://docs.arangodb.com/cookbook/JavaDriverXmlData.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are two proper solutions.
One is to put the whole XML into an attribute of a document. This will then in term probably be not good for doing AQL queries on the payload of the xml.

Another possible approach could be to use [jsonml](http://www.jsonml.org/) to translate your xml into structured json documents, and store them [using their java library](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONML.html). I don't know how well this scales on complex XML like SOAP though.

You could then create AQL queries to work on that collection and `FILTER` for attributes of the source XML.

Comment: That means for every xml data i first have to convert it into json document format n then push it into arango... Is it so?

Comment: in the jsonml case - correct. The node module has a binary dependency on the expat xml parser and will therefore not work inside of a [ArangoDB FOXX-Service](https://www.arangodb.com/foxx/)

Comment: Maybe we find the time on Friday to have a look howto smart wrap it around the arangodb java driver.

Comment: one more question regarding arango full text search......when I am do PUT <br/> http://localhost:8529//_api/simple/fulltext  { 
  "collection" : "Metadata", 
  "attribute" : "metadata", 
  "query" : "defined"
}  <br/>    I get this as result :  {
  "result": [],
  "hasMore": false,
  "count": 0,
  "error": false,
  "code": 201
}    I don't understand what's the problem here ......can you help me out here ?

Comment: [question handled in othen stackoverflow issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780431/how-to-use-full-text-search-with-arango-rest-api-as-im-always-getting-empty-res/34786853#34786853)