# How to use full text search with arango REST API as I'm always getting empty result?

Tags: json, api, arangodb, arangojs

Data in Arango:

```
{
 "employees": [
    {
      "lastName": "Ansari",
      "firstName": "Haseb"
    },
    {
      "lastName": "Ansari",
      "firstName": "Affan"
    },
    {
      "lastName": "Keshav",
      "firstName": "Anil"
    }
  ],
  "_id": "test/124518952473",
  "_rev": "124518952473",
  "_key": "124518952473"
}
```

Indexing:
POST              http://localhost:8529/_db/db_test/_api/index?collection=test

Body:

```
{
 "type" : "fulltext", 
 "fields" : [ 
   "lastName" 
  ] 
}
```

Searching:

PUT                  http://localhost:8529/_db/db_test/_api/simple/fulltext

Body:

```
{ 
  "collection" : "test", 
  "attribute" : "lastName", 
  "query" : "Ansari" 
}
```

I want in my application to use REST API for full text search. Please help me where I am going wrong here. And this is one document in arango store just for example. Otherwise, i'll be having more documents hence full-text search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: Your index is not on a field in your document.

Long:
You're saving one document, it has a list `employees`, but no document `lastname` - thats inside of `employees` but this won't match the path.

You can however make it work if you put the fulltext index on `employees`, then all attributes of the object `employees` will be indexed. You then however will match on first *and* last name.

If you want to do this separate, you need to directly match a token like that:
`employees[0].lastName`